# No Mongo Query gets result when cron is running in background

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

I have been NodeJS as server side and MongoDB as our database. It really works great together.

Now I have added `node-schedule` library into our system , to call a function like a cron-job.

The process takes around hours to complete.

My issue is whenever cron is running , all users to my site gets No response fro server i.e database gets locked.

Stuck on the issue from a week , needs good solution to run cron , without affecting users using the site.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will want to write a worker and run the worker in a different entry point that is not part of your server.  There are multiple ways you could achieve this.

1) Write a worker on another server to interact with your database

2) Write a service worker on another server that interacts with your api

3) Use the same server but setup a cronjob to execute the file that does the work at a specified time.

<strike>But you should not do this from the same entry point that your server is running on.  You need a different execution file.</strike>

There is one thing you can do to run this where it will not bog down your server and that would be for your trigger for node-schedule to run a child process. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html